# Unity-Tweak-Tool is not starting from Ubuntu Dash

Tags: unity, 12.10, unity-dash, unity-tweak-tool

I've installed the tool unity-tweak-tool, but I couldn't start it from Dash.

I can launch it from terminal though. Please advise how can I make the dash icon work?

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean "Launcher".

1. Right click the Unity-Tweak-Tool icon on Launcher and select "Unlock from Launcher"
2. Launch it from Terminal
3. Right click the Unity-Tweak-Tool icon on Launcher and select "Lock to Launcher"

This icon now should allow you to launch it from Launcher.

**Please also make sure that you have properly installed it by following these steps:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Source: [www.iloveubuntu.net/unity-tweak-tool-002-adds-new-features](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/unity-tweak-tool-002-adds-new-features)

Comment: Nope, not working. My ubuntu is 64 bit Desktop. I even tried removing & installing again, still same issue.

Comment: I've just installed it (didn't need it before as I already have Ubuntu Tweak, Unsettings, etc.) and it works without any such problems on my Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit desktop. 1) Can you check if its launcher file is ok by making sure that when you enter terminal command: gedit '/usr/share/applications/unity-tweak-tool.desktop' you can see this line: Exec=/usr/bin/unity-tweak-tool %f 2) Next thing to check can be what error messages are displayed when you enter terminal command: unity-tweak-tool

Comment: command "unity-tweak-tool" throwing some long error(which i couldn't paste here) but it is starting normally with "sudo unity-tweak-tool" command

Comment: it might be because of a corruption in your user configuration for unity-tweak-tool. you might perhaps try starting it again after deleting this sub-folder (unity-tweak-tool only, and certainly not the .config parent folder!) in your home folder altogether: ~/.config/unity-tweak-tool/

Comment: As of now, UTT has no user config files. Debug logs will be enabled soon..(WIP) @Mahesh, please hop on to [#freyja-dev on freenode IRC](http://goo.gl/eeZkJ) to help us solve the issue. someone or the other will be available there round the clock.